# viTables and HDFView Memory Errors when opening large CArray

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

Both viTables and HDFView return memory errors when opening a large carray generated from pytables code. It appears that the viewer attempts to read the entire carray into memory and fails. Is this actually the case or am I mising something?

Open the carray directly from a python script and attempting to print the entire carray also produces a memory error.

Creating a hdf5 with a carray as follows:

```
import tables as pytab
pytfile = pytab.File("bigcarray.hdf",'w','Test of Big CArray')
grpData = pytfile.createGroup('/','data')
pytfile.createCArray(grpData,'TestData',pytab.Float64Atom(), (10000,10000))
pytfile.close()
```

and opening in either viTable or HDFView results in the memory error problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce on Linux. But I wouldn't call 4 KB "big".

Comment: I get a memory error if I use an array of size `100000000x100000000`. Are you using Python 64 bits?

Comment: I am using the 32bit version. Thanks for asking the question as this is likely the problem. Investigating ...    10K*10K*8bytes=0.8GB